# my website urls via apache2 dont work

Tags: django, apache2, mod-python

my first question for this site, i hope it goes well!!

I have, ubuntu, apache2, python, django and mod_python.

All is installed properly.
I have created a website project which works properly when i run it locally.
But i cant get it working the same way on apache.
I can access my website project directories, but i cant access my website projects URL's
I think this has something to do with incorrectly configuring my  directives in the httpd.conf file. Also when i type the server name in the web browser i get a server not found

a quick rundown:

My project lives in /home/jamie/mysite
django, apache, modpython on root directory

in /etc/apache2/sites-available/http.conf i have:

NameVirtualHost 111.22.33.44

```
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/jamie/mysite

    <Directory />

        Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None

    </Directory>

    <Location "/mysite">

        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        #removed line -PythonHandler mod_python.publisher- didnt work#
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
        PythonPath "['/home/jamie/', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages'] + sys.path"
        PythonAutoReload On
        PythonDebug On  

    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

ANybody that can help me i will give **1 BILLION DOLLARS** to

---

ok akonsu cheers for this.

http//localhost/templates points to my templates folder and shows all the files and subdirectories. http//localhost/templates/homepage.html will show the homepage.html located in the templates folder with all the ugly django tags that go with it.

I want run my website app on apache the same way as if i ran it locally, via the urls.
example. http//localhost/homepage would point directly to the file homepage.html which is located in the templates folder as this is how it is set out in the urls.py file and would not show the ugly django tags.

If i do type in http//localhost/homepage via the apache server i get the url /homepage does not exist on this server

The django book tells me to point DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to my apps settings file, which i have done 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings'  The settings file points to the urls file which points to the views file which in turn renders with template files and so on and so forth. Thus if i typed http//localhost/homepage it should work as homepage has been configured properly in my urls.py file. I believe i have done what they have asked but still no luck. Either im getting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE part wrong or starting with /localhost is wrong.

I dont know what difference this makes but if i change the servername in the httpd.conf file to say www.blabla.com it wont throw an error when i restart apache server, meaning it's configured right. But when i type www.blabla.com in the browser i get an error saying this site does not exist.

Comment: and I will give you billion dollars for switching to mod_wsgi (instead of mod_python) http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/

Answer (score 0):

try removing `PythonHandler mod_python.publisher`

Comment: Cheers for the reply but sorry mate, nothing changed.

Comment: what are the symptoms? what do you mean that you cannot access your URLs? what does the server return?